# auto and auto& and const

Tags: c++, c++11, constants, auto

```
auto x1 = exp1;
auto& x2 = exp2;
```

Do I understand correctly that variables declared with `auto` (x1) will never be `const`, even if `exp1` is `const` (for ex. a function that returns `const`). When with `auto&`(x2) will be const if exp2 will be const. Even if auto is a pointer.

```
auto it = find(cont.cbegin(), cont.cend(), value);
```

Here despite I use cbegin and cend it will be non-const iterator, and to be const_iterator I should write

```
const auto it1 = find(cont.cbegin(), cont.cend(), value);
```

Comment: `cbegin` (and `cend`) will return a `const_iterator` regardless.

Comment: "_When with auto&(x2) will be const if exp2 will be const._" No. `auto` will never be `const`, or a reference, unless explicitly specified (i.e. `auto const& x2`). Not writing an answer, due to me being too lazy to find the quote from the standard.

Comment: `const_iterator` is not a const. `const auto` is `const const_iterator`, not `const_iterator`.

Comment: How qualifiers implicitly associate through the type system in C++ is a bit convoluted, and more convoluted with templates.  Keep in mind that `auto` is a *type* that is deduced by the compiler, which will be its own object.  But `auto&` is a reference, and qualifiers are stickier with references because they are *aliases*.  (Orthogonal, but also adds to the confusion:  `const` is not transitive.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Do I understand correctly that variables declared with auto (x1) will never be const

Correct.

> When with auto&(x2) will be const if exp2 will be const.

A reference is never const; references cannot be cv qualified. `x2` could be a reference **to** const.

> ```
> auto it = find(cont.cbegin(), cont.cend(), value);
> ```
>
> Here despite I use cbegin and cend it will be non-const iterator

`it` would be a non-const qualified object of const_iterator type.

> ```
> const auto it1 = find(cont.cbegin(), cont.cend(), value);
> ```

`it1` would be a const qualified object of const_iterator type.

Indirecting through a const_iterator (typically) gives you a reference to const, and thus you cannot modify the pointed object.

A const object cannot (generally) be modified. Thus, you for example cannot increment a const qualified iterator.